# PostgreSQL Select WHERE column = [Array]

Tags: postgresql

I have a table1 with column 1 and 2

```
1        2
Banana   x
Apple    y
Orange   z
```

I want to call a SELECT on this table with an array as parameter: ['Banana', 'Apple']

I want to get the rows where column 1 contains Banana or Apple (elements of the array)

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 = 'Banana OR column1 = 'Apple'
```

But how is this working dynamically? Like where column1 = elemt in array....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ANY` operator:

```
select *
from the_table
where the_column = any( array['Banana', 'Apple'] );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the keyword `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 IN ('Banana', 'Apple');
```

(reference doc.: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#AEN16806)